# Moving platform ( website,mobile apps) from old Azure account to new one

Tags: android, ios, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

Platform is currently hosted in developer's account who has one subscription and many other platforms beside mine so asking Azure support to do transfer is not the option. That being said i need to recreate whole thing on my new account. What is the best practice, standard procedure for this, one that will have the minimal downtime and impact on users? Any previous experience dealing with something like that? Thanks.

Comment: When you say asking Azure support to transfer the resources is not an option, does that mean that you have tried with a support call and your request was rejected? This is the type of resource transfer that Azure support _should_ help you with...
I have had support move resources between different subscriptions and tenants, as long as you can identify the resources you want to move _and_ those resources support move (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources) it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all your resources in a resource group, you can export the ARM template.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates

Once you have the appropriate ARM template, you apply it to your new subscription, and it will recreate all the resources.  Note that you will need to change names - the azurewebsites.net namespace is global (as are all DNS names), so you can't re-use the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before.

1. Create a new subscription in the developer account
2. Move the services you want from the other subscription to this subscription (keep in mind some resources cannot be moved, so make sure you inventory all your items in the portal and see if they can be moved before you start this)
3. Transfer the new subscription into your new account.
4. Move the services from this new subscription to your production subscription
5. Delete the temporary subscription

Make sure to wait sometime between transfer steps, sometimes the transfer takes a long time and if you prematurely move things it will break and you will be in trouble.
You can do all this on your own